# javascript newbie: what's the right way to apply the same behavior to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript

I'm taking my first adventure with javascript, and totally without my bearings.  I'd like to show a thumbnail that opens a modal with a larger view of the picture (and this is really the only front end fanciness I'll need, so I'm trying to keep it simple). I've copied [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img) code from w3schools, which uses getElementById. It works great for the first image on the page but clicking subsequent images doesn't pop anything up.  Reading around on stack overflow it sounds like that's because I'm matching on the id, but each element on the page will/should have a different id (which makes sense).

I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569701/javascript-open-window-changed-to-modal) where the person made the ids unique by appending the element's id.  I could do something like that, but I (a) wanted to check if that's kosher and (b) then obviously the id will no longer match, so is there some different attribute I would tack on to match up my HTML with my styles?  This must be a common problem- what's the right way to apply the same behavior to multiple elements on a page? For example I can give them

thanks!

**UPDATE**: based on everyone's feedback below I've modified the code to use getElementByClassName instead of getElementById- see gist here: https://gist.github.com/dianekaplan/1602a7c0a1c1ec6aa103b61d6530ff15

If I'm reading the code correctly, then the important lines for me to change are from line 115 to line 116- (to set the image info based on ClassName, not id)- and replacing 'myImg' with popup' in the style lines 5 and 11, but clicking the first image no longer opens the modal, so I missed something.  Anyone see what's wrong that I need for it to work?

Comment: CSS classes, JS functions or objects. I suggest reading [the JS guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) or a similar book first, followed by [CSS tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/CSS).

Comment: IDs do need to be unique. But if you're applying the same behaviour to multiple elements I wouldn't recommend using IDs at all, I'd give all of the elements the same class and then select them by class.

Comment: You could assign a `class` to the elements you want to target. Then CSS and Javascript can be attached to everything with that class.

Comment: You may also want to research event delegation, especially if you're dealing with dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Okay I updated three spots as needed (see updated description and gist) but I have something wrong because clicking either image no longer brings up the modal.  Anyone see what the problem is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a class name (the same in all img) instead of ids and then use `getElementsByClassName()` to fetch all of them, instead of `getElementsById()` which gets only one (as ids must be unique).

Then, you should store the full size image's url somehow in order to fetch it regardless of which img was clicked. One way may be using data attributes.

Example:

```
<img src="thumb1.jpg" data-fullsize="full1.jpg" class="popup">
<img src="thumb2.jpg" data-fullsize="full2.jpg" class="popup">
<img src="thumb3.jpg" data-fullsize="full3.jpg" class="popup">
```

---

```
var elems=document.getElementsByClassName("popup");
for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
    elems[i].onclick=function() {
         var fullsize=this.dataset.fullsize;
         //open de popup, fullsize has the clicked image url
    }
}
```

Code not tested, for the idea only.

Comment: Thank you, @Gabriel!  I've updated my code now to use getElementByClassName- see gist, I *think* I got the three places where it needs to change, but it's not working... let me know if you see what I did wrong, but it's possible I'm missing something larger, like what you and one of the other helpful folks said about storing the data.  The trick is I won't know what images are on the page until I get there (my controller is passing a bunch of records to the view, different every time).  It feels like this should be simple, but javascript is turning out to be a tough one to make friends with...

Comment: The first thing I see in your code is that it is `getElementsByClassName` no `getElementByClassName`. This returns an array of elements, this means that you should loop through the array assigning the onclick event to each element (like my sample code). Are the thumbnail and the full image the same jpg file?

Comment: Ah I figured that was too easy.  Makes sense that it'll have all the elements using that class name.  Yes the thumbnail and the full image will use the same file in every case.  Tonight when I get home I'll fix my typo, try again, and revisit your example above.  thank you!

Comment: If the thumb and the full image are the same file, then you don't need to worry about storing the file names, just use the `src` like you're doing now, but apply the event to each element returned by `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: you're right!!!!  I just updated my gist with what's working on the w3schools example- (https://gist.github.com/dianekaplan/1602a7c0a1c1ec6aa103b61d6530ff15)- and I reflected it in my project and it works there too! I'm so happy!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your primary question ID's are "supposed to" [1] be unique so unless you came up with a convention such as a prefix or regex you couldn't easily use them to group elements together.

If you want to group together multiple elements you could use a class, instead, in which case instead of `getElementById` you'd use [`getElementsByClassName`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

That being said I wouldn't recommend that either; using vanilla JavaScript can be very time-consuming to make a complex application.  You will be tempted to merge the UI with all your functionality.  This works great for smaller applications but it can become very unruly, particularly if you don't take steps to allow yourself to refactor in the future, in which case you'll be stuck with an application few can easily be trained on and modify.

You are correct to learn the language, though, prior to a framework.  JavaScript is *especially* quirky.

I would suggest if you're looking to create a web application to look into a modern JavaScript framework after learning JavaScript, HTML and CSS.  (And focus on having a practice to being able to refactor/upgrade/improve otherwise you'll be stuck in 2016 and it'll be 2020 - you don't have to worry about this immediately, but start learning about how to do that while you're learning the language.)

To find frameworks I would suggest exploring what's out there.  [Here's an example of one on GitHub.](https://github.com/showcases/front-end-javascript-frameworks)  That's probably a hand-coded list.  It's also good to explore exhaustive lists, such as just looking at the ["most starred" Repositories on GitHub that are written in JavaScript](https://github.com/search?l=&o=desc&q=language%3AJavaScript&ref=advsearch&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).  And of course check elsewhere besides GitHub, too.

---

I happen to know AngularJS the best and it happens to be one of the most popular but I would recommend for you to explore and find one that has syntax you like.  You might find a different one more intuitive. [Here's a plunker that shows how to solve that problem in AngularJS](https://plnkr.co/edit/gA8XFGbOwfDumx6oj7lh?p=preview).

Notice how all the functionality is separate from the UI and how declarative it is - the `main` directive has no idea how the images are being rendered - it just says here are some image url's and descriptions:

```
scope.images = [{
  url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg',
  description: 'Trolltunga, Norway'
},{
  url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg',
  description: 'Other Description'
},{
  url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg',
  description: 'Another Description'
}];
```

This is what initializes the app: `<html ng-app="plunker">` and `<main></main>` is akin to the "main method" in that it is the component that calls all the other components.

It's much easier to test an app's functionality if you're careful to separate out the presentation concerns from the rest of the app.  It will take a while to learn JavaScript and probably any framework, though, so don't expect too much too soon if you're just getting your hands wet in JavaScript - but if you've programmed for a while you already know this :)

(Disclaimer: What I did isn't necessarily the "best practices" as I tried to simplify it a bit so as to not overwhelm OP too much with information, although the added complexity is useful in more advanced scenarios.)

---

[1] "Supposed to" meaning browsers may do their best to render a page, even it isn't "compliant" HTML.  Web Applications suffer from having to have the same code work on different browsers, operating systems and versions of each all implementing the standards (or choosing not to) differently.  It's a nightmare if you haven't ran into it, yet.

Comment: wow- thank you, everybody!  @Gabriel your answer really spells it out- I've just done something that took me a step back so I'm going to come back with a fresh brain in the morning before I do more damage.  I think this will be the way though- thank you.  Lots of different/good ideas here- thank you everyone!

Comment: @DianeKaplan No problem! I added an example in my answer to demonstrate what I was talking about.  Good luck!

Comment: Whoa, @Words_Like_Jared!  Now that I see what you put together- thank you!!!!  And I can even see it working :):):)  Question: I won't know what images will be on the page until it loads (I have a controller passing a set of records to the view)- how can I adapt your solution to this case?

Comment: @DianeKaplan You're welcome!! Well if you're using C# MVC that kind of works against Angular a little since they solve some of the same problems (dynamic HTML).  Instead of having the server generate the HTML in MVC you'd have the Angular client make an HTTP GET request to the server and store the result inside the client-side directive link function.  You would normally use something like C# Web API with Angular: https://plnkr.co/edit/EAmUh1OfcwqZRL8dXHbC?p=preview  It's much easier to reuse a Web API than MVC endpoints (you get a set of endpoints that is just data not data + how to display)

Comment: @DianeKaplan (I couldn't tell which MVC framework you were using, for sure; I was guessing.) While C# MVC + C# Server + EF Model First is cool because you do everything in C# for complicated applications only the C# Server ends up being "nice", imo; you'll end up fighting EF and MVC - I prefer client-side frameworks and focused servers on just focusing on reading and writing through SQL on top of something like Dapper.

Comment: @DianeKaplan You're going to get lots of different opinions from everyone, especially on the internet.  Especially people shouting "best practices" and "anti-patterns" without understanding why or at least explaining it; if you have a say in the framework it's probably better to form opinions yourself - make sample applications in each framework and see what it's like and then decide, I would say.  If you can't change frameworks for whatever reason, then you should learn how to solve the problem with your given framework (and probably start to solve the refactoring problem).

Comment: thank you!  And to answer your question I'm actually not using an mvc framework for this small project; it's just straight php, where some files are views and some files are acting as controllers- my hope is to keep things simple.